# Get class of EnumSet's Enum

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to get the class of the `Enum` from a variable of type `EnumSet`.

Consider the following code:

```
enum Foo
{
    FOO_0,
    FOO_1,
}

<E extends Enum<E>> void fooBar(EnumSet<E> enumSet, Class<E> type)
{
    EnumSet<E> none = EnumSet.noneOf(type);
    // ...
}

void bar()
{
    EnumSet<Foo> enumSet = EnumSet.of(Foo.FOO_1);
    fooBar(enumSet, Foo.class);
}
```

Writing `Foo.class` in `fooBar()` seems redundant. I would like to extract the `class` from the `enumSet` inside `fooBar()` function. Is that even possible?

What I wish to do is just call `fooBar(enumSet);` and still be able to instantiate the `none` variable as `EnumSet.noneOf()`.

Comment: What should noneOf() do? What's the first argument for?

Comment: @JBNizet It does not matter for the question. Maybe I should have given the method a more random name.

Comment: @rozina it does matter, because your question is currently unclear. Please add more information about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: "get the Foo.class from the variable enumSet inside fooBar() function." You can only do that if `enumSet` is non-empty: `enumSet.iterator().next().getClass()`. If it's empty, you're stuck. (And that also doesn't quite work if the first enum element in the set defines a class body).

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for empty `EnumSet`s also, and returns the correct `enum` type even when the element has a class body:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Class<T> getElementType(EnumSet<T> enumSet) {
    if (enumSet.isEmpty())
        enumSet = EnumSet.complementOf(enumSet);
    return enumSet.iterator().next().getDeclaringClass();
}
```

Comment: That's a cunning way to handle the empty set problem!

Comment: Seems quite the runtime overhead, but it does work. Thank you!